# Windows Embedded OpengGL ES in XAML

Tags: xaml, opengl-es, windows-embedded-compact, windows-embedded

I am trying to figure out if either Windows Embedded Compact 2013 or 7 will allow me to have an OpenGL ES view inside my XAML UI. For both I can get a lot of information on how the system can use OpenGL to run the actual XAML engine as to enhance performance but I cannot seem to figure out if it would be possible to embed an OpenGL view. Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, The easiest way to do it is to host a winForms control in the XAML and use the window handle of that control to create the OpenGL ES surface.

The hard way is to use Platform Builder to edit the XAMLRendererPlugin and expose the context, surface and display as well as changing the way it renders to use bound buffers and add extra calls to glUseProgram. Although the advantage of this method is that you can now render directly to the XAML surface on SWE